# Using initQgis() on headless installation of QGIS 3?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3

When running PyQGIS testing 2.99 the following coredumps:

```
from qgis.core import *
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr", False)
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()
```

How to start migrating PyQGIS scripts to the upcoming QGIS 3?

Answer (score 7):

See http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/embedded-linux.html :

> Since the Qt 5.0 release, Qt no longer 
>   contains its own window system (QWS) implementation.

One solution (apart from e.g. setting the DISPLAY environment variable to some X-over-ssh value) is:

```
export  QT_QPA_PLATFORM=offscreen
```

The programmatical way in Python is:

```
import os
from qgis.core import *
os.environ["QT_QPA_PLATFORM"] = "offscreen"
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr", False)
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()
```

Comment: Just tried this on a clean install of QGIS 3.0 (Python 3.6 and PyQt5), and it failed at `QgsApplication.setPrefixPath` line. Strangely, it runs no problem in the QGIS python console. I've setup all of the necessary environment variables on my Windows 7.